# How to delete internal intesected faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, knife-tool

The following mesh is created by converting a curve with bevel effect like below:

[image]

The mesh has some faces which extrude into the inside of the shape. This effect can be seen by cutting the mesh into halves (using boolean modifier):

[image]

If I want to get rid of the internal faces and only retain the outside faces which can be seen from this graph, what is the best way to achieve that without too much manual work? (I have a lot of characters to deal with, so I am seeking an automatic way)

[image]

I have tried clean the mesh up and use "Intersect (Knife)", but that does not do the job cleanly. It still misses some faces and leaving them extruded inside the shape. Basically I only want to keep the contour of the mesh.

Attached a [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODN-qWTyAgNkjdEjpPl0jTWrWai2V_VD) for demo.

Comment: your topology seems a bit crazy, are you sure you've chosen the best possible topology to build your object?

Comment: The topology is created simply by beveling a curve of a letter. What are some other alternatives to achieve the same effect? I am only concerned with getting the "outside crust"

Comment: could you please show a picture or a drawing of the shape you want?

Comment: The last picture is what I want, but with all the faces underneath the surface removed

Comment: so you could select the faces you want to keep with the lasso, then inverse the selection with ctrl i, and delete, all the invisible faces will be deleted, does it work?

Comment: Not quite. Some faces on the surface partially extrude inside the shape. So even if I delete the inverse, the inside portion of those surfaces faces still remain inside the shape. It is easier to see this if you try out my example (attached at the end of the original post)

Comment: yes I see, but your topology is super messy, for example you have faces crossing through each others, that's why I was asking you what you were trying to do, because you should completely redo it from scratch

Comment: Having a beveled character is my goal. Because the stoke of the character is so thin, I want to taper-extrude it to have a thicker support for 3D print. Straight extrusion, followed by tapering does not work, because it does not generate omnidirectional base (It at most skews the baseline shape). The bevel effect of a curve, however, does extend to all directions. And that is how I created the topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shrinkwrap is actually the best way I can found and it works pretty well. Comparing to the heightmap approach talked about here [BlenderExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101249/cant-remove-unnecessary-geometry-in-object?rq=1#answer-101317), the shrinkwrap approach is easier to operate and involves less processes.

Here is how I do it, first create a plane mesh over the beveled object, subdivide the surface with 30 slices:

[image: ![image|690x473](upload://qA7NklU4vR5BkVgdaNUDj1rjehq.png)]

Add subdivision surface and shrinkwrap modifiers.  The subdivisions need to set to 4 or 5. The mode of the shrinkwrap need to be "Project" (You might need to turn on "Negative" if "Positive" doesn't work.)

[image: ![image|690x413](upload://50My2LsquPzNMTgz0iYbsBLM4Wa.png)]

Apply the modifiers and edit the mesh. To do this easily, go to a side view and box select the vertices on the top layer, remove the vertexes:

[image: ![image|668x500](upload://vleYQjJtkj3z8yxdQbVjECQONbr.png)]

Then you get a beautiful top contour without internal intervening faces:

[image: ![image|690x447](upload://mWVBfgiIlK3sCmJFgAuHVb35n4q.png)]

The shape will have more details then necessary. Use limited dissolve to fix that

[image: ![image|570x500](upload://wiy6SAKTpNAntLsF6ebwfakBZR9.png)]

End result:

[image]